# Can I use OUTPUT INTO to add data to a relational table with additional values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One holds common data for articles, and the other holds translations for text. Something like this:

Articles Table

`id | key | date`

Translations Table

`id | article_key | lang | title | content`

`key` is a string and is the primary key.

`article_key` is a foreign key relating it to articles on the `key` column.

When I add a new row to the Articles, I'd like to be able to use the `key` that was just inserted and add a new row to the Translations Table.

I've read about `OUTPUT INTO` but it doesn't seem like I can add other values to the Translations table. Also I get an error about it being on either side of a relationship.

Is my only course of action to `INSERT` into Articles followed by an `INSERT` with a `SELECT` subquery to get the `key`?

Edit: Expected output would be something like:

Articles

```
id | key | date
---------------
1  | somekey | 2018-05-31
```

Article Translations

```
id | article_key | lang | title | content
-----------------------------------------
1  | somekey     | en   | lorem | ipsum
```

Comment: use scope_identity() to grab the identity value from the last inserted record to a table

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: What technology is this MSSQL, MYSQL, Oracle, other?

Comment: Please tag the DB and provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Whoops, sorry - it's MSSQL

Comment: @DanielMarcus I don't have an Identity column. Only the pk, which is a string. My understanding is that scope_identity() requires an int Identity column.

Comment: @shrek Ok done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this could work based on your description:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Articles TABLE (id INT NOT NULL
  , [key] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , [date] DATE NOT NULL);

DECLARE @ArticleTranslations TABLE (id INT NOT NULL
  , article_key VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , lang VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , content VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

INSERT @Articles (id, [key], [date]) -- This is insert into @Articles
OUTPUT INSERTED.id, INSERTED.[key], 'en', 'lorem', 'ipsum' -- This is insert into @ArticleTranslations
INTO @ArticleTranslations (id, article_key, lang, title, content) -- This is insert into @ArticleTranslations
VALUES (1, 'somekey', GETDATE()); -- This is insert into @Articles

SELECT *
FROM @Articles;

SELECT *
FROM @ArticleTranslations;
```

Try this out Stack Exchange: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/857925

Maybe it's not that simple as it is. So let me know whether this works or not.

Comment: Hmm. I think this would work but I'm getting an error about OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a relationship. This definitely explained how `OUTPUT INTO` works though. :D

Comment: What kind of relationship do you have? Put that to your question :)

Comment: `article_key` is a foreign key to articles. After a little research, it looks like I would need to output into a temp table first.

Comment: Yep. So this is going to be almost exactly what you need. Keep `@ArticleTranslations` table variable. Just then do a second insert from it into actual table.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This does work perfectly. One question: is there a way to add multiple rows with output? Like if I wanted to add a row for 'en' as well as 'es'?

Comment: Yeah. Output will work for as many rows as your database can handle. Just be aware that table variable normally handles up to thousand records. If you got more, use a temporary table instead.

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to find the syntax for inserting multiple rows from one output. I tried adding an additional `OUTPUT` line, but that didn't work. Parenthesis with columns didn't work neither.

Comment: Ah. You would have to inset ES into your first table first. Basically amount of records inserted into first table is equal to the amount of records inserted in output clause.

Comment: Ok. So it seems like I'll have to do something different since the "en", and "es" would be inserted into the second table. The `article_key` would be the same for both of them since it's a translations table, but the rest of the values would be different. Thanks :)

Comment: You can play around with that temporary table that you got. 